# Visual Studio Code: Java application and remote debugging

Tags: java, docker, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I'm trying to figure out how to configure Visual Studio Code in order to remote debug a Java application.

The application starts in a Docker container and I need to attach the debugger in the proper way.

With Eclipse (STS) is easy because there is the Remote Java Application config where you define

```
- application
- host 
- port
```

and It works, unfortunately I didn't understand how to make the same thing on Visual Studio Code.
Reading this article: "https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_creating-a-devcontainerjson-file" was not helping for me.

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: I didn't ever do it in VS, but I think you need to install the Java Debugger plugin, if not already. In any case, unless you really have to, I wouldn't recommend VS. "Traditional" Java IDEs like Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA etc. are around for a longer time, and are specialized for Java.

Comment: @HarisOsmanagić Yes I know Eclipse is specialized for Java and I use it since 2010 for that but I'm trying to understand if VSC is a valid alternative for Spring Boot + Docker development. At the moment the only problem for me is the remote debugging. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: you could fill in the `mainClass` for `Launch` setting or `hostName` and `port`for `Attach` in your `launch.json` ,refer to [Debug Java Applications](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/09/28/java-debug)